# Extra Whitespace generated on the top of page?

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

This is a very weird bug I'm having.
I'm using Modernizer and after a whole bunch of troubleshooting I've pretty much narrowed it down to Modernizer generating this big block of whitespace.

I can check the server on my local server via 'localhost' and get this whitespace
[image: Localhost]

I would perform the same check with the same browser but with my WAN IP instead and get a different whitespace. It's really odd.
[image: WAN]

**Link:** You can check it out here:
http://184.161.181.41:8888/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I change `margin-top` to `padding-top` on `#wrapper`, everything works fine and the title stays below the floating bar.
[image]

Comment: What's weird is that this fix, doesn't seem to change fix the problem when I view the website via 'localhost'. It's probably browser cache problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you have a 43px margin-top in `#wrapper`. Change it to 0px.

```
#wrapper {
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the reason I have margin-top on #wrapper is so the 'fixed' #nav doesn't cover all of it up. Unfortunately, that's not my problem.

Comment: I cannot test how it looks on localhost, it's not possible to see the difference you are taking about.

Comment: The difference doesn't matter at the moment. What matters is: What is generating that white-space in the first place and how to prevent it from rendering.

Comment: It's impossible to tell by just looking at the code. Screenshots alone are not enough. We need to be able to test the differences you are talking about.

Comment: Well, I've included a link to the website itself. What kind of additional things could I get for you? I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this one.